# if/else shorthand in coffeescript?

Tags: coffeescript

```
if myString then myString else ""
```

... feels a bit verbose.

Is there a shorter alternative I could use?

`myString` may be either undefined or a string.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
myString ? ''
```

And this is what you *actually* want because it compiles to:

```
(typeof myString !== "undefined" && myString !== null ? myString : '')
```

Note that you can use this existence operator for any value, e.g.

```
myFloat ? 90.8
```

Answer (score 6):

How about this one:

```
myString or ""
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the existential operator:

```
myString ?= ""
```